# Athena: Skip Header line with LazySimpleSerde

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

Would like to know if it is possible to skip the header line in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe` in Aws Athena. I have tried `tblproperties ( 'skip.header.line.count' = '1' )` but doesn't work. I header it works with OpenCSVSerDe but it seems to support only `string` data type which will end up a lot of work in the query.

Answer (score 4):

I have just tried the following:

Create a CSV and upload it to S3:

```
breed_id, breen_name, category
1,pug,toy
2,German Shepard,working,
3,Scottish Terrier,Working
```

Run the following DDL in Athena:

```
create external table dogs (
  breed_id int, 
  breen_name string, 
  category string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
;
```

Then run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "default"."dogs" LIMIT 10;
```

Yielding the following result:

[image]